# Python unittesting for a class method

Tags: python, unit-testing

A beginner level question.. trying to understand how I can best use the built-in `unittest`. In the trivial example below, the method consume_food picks a food item and then I am calling `food.cut()` method.
In future, this method may return instance of `Drink` object. The `#commented code` indicates one possible future implementation. In this case, `self.milk` will not have the cut method defined.

I want to add a unit test for `consume_food` and `pick_food` methods. I would like to do this for the original implementation first and then change it after adding `self.milk` functionality.

**EDIT:** The intention is to write a unit test for an existing api, so that I can capture any such changes ( i.e. absence of `Drink.cut` method) forcing me to update the methods and unit tests.

Can someone please help showing me how to write a unit test for this example?

```
class Fruit:
    def cut(self):
        print("cut the fruit")

class Drink:
    def pour(self):
       print("pour the drink")


class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.apple = Fruit()
       self.banana=Fruit()
       #self.milk = Drink()
       #self.liquid_diet = True

   def consume_food(self):
       food = pick_food()
       food.cut()
       print("consuming the food")

   def pick_food(self):
       return self.apple                                 
       #if self.liquid_diet: return self.milk
       #return self.apple
```

Comment: I think apart from unittesting you need to think about what your API is going to be.  Right now your API is such that `consume_food` assumes that all foods can be cut.  If you write a unittest that relies on being able to call `food.cut()`, then it will fail if you add foods that do not have `.cut()`.  That is unavoidable; you can't write a test that will always keep working no matter how you change the API.  So I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: @BrenBarn I think that's exactly what OP: To provide a test that will fail once the assumption that all foods can be cut isn't true any more, forcing him to refactor his code before implementing the new feature.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Okay, so any test that calls `consume_food` at all will do that.

Comment: @BrenBarn: That is one of the intentions. I want to write a test for an existing api, so that I can capture any such changes ( i.e. absence of `Drink.cut` method)... yes, I can add some hasattr/ assertion or isinstance condition, but the thing I wanted to learn is , 'can I use  unittest' here? if so how to write one? can someone please show me for this example please? I understand that it will need to be changed in future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The thing is, your `cut()` and `consume_food()` methods don't really do much right now that allow you to make meaningful [assertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_assertion) after you execute them in a test.

So I'd suggest to expand your initial code a little bit to have those methods act upon the respective objects so that you can make meaningful assertions on their state after invoking those methods.

Right now, all they really do is write to STDOUT, which is sort of a global state - which should [generally be avoided](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) and is [always difficult to test](http://googletesting.blogspot.ch/2008/11/clean-code-talks-global-state-and.html). (I'm not saying that printing output is a bad thing - but if that's the *only* thing your code does, it's going to be very tricky to test).

So I introduced a common superclass `Food` which has a `consume()` method, and sets a corresponding attribute. Similarly, the `cut()` method on `Fruit` now sets an attribute that you can test for.

```
import unittest


class Food(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.consumed = False

    def consume(self):
        self.consumed = True


class Fruit(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fruit, self).__init__()
        self.been_cut = False

    def cut(self):
        print("cut the fruit")
        self.been_cut = True


class Consumer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.apple = Fruit()
        self.banana = Fruit()

    def consume_food(self):
        food = self.pick_food()
        food.cut()
        print("consuming the food")
        food.consume()

    def pick_food(self):
        return self.apple
```

These tests now can make assertions on the object's states after the relevant methods have been invoked. Note that they follow the [AAA pattern - Arrange Act Assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert):

- First, you **arrange** the objects under test the way you need them (instantiate a consumer).
- Then you **act** on the objects under test (invoking the method in question)
- Finally, you make **assertions** on the resulting state you expect the objects to be in

```
class TestConsumer(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_consume_food_consumes_the_apple(self):
        c = Consumer()
        c.consume_food()
        self.assertTrue(c.apple.consumed,
                        "Expected apple to be consumed")

    def test_consume_food_cuts_the_food(self):
        c = Consumer()
        c.consume_food()
        self.assertTrue(c.apple.been_cut,
                        "Expected apple to be cut")

    def test_pick_food_always_selects_the_apple(self):
        c = Consumer()
        food = c.pick_food()
        self.assertEquals(c.apple, food,
                          "Expected apple to have been picked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thank you!  the print statements were added just for creating this example. Now I understand how to write a basic test in such cases.